# How to set a Monospace Font for Dashboard Sticky Notes Widget?

Tags: dashboard-widget, font

I would like to use a monospaced font on the Sticky Notes in Apple's Dashboard widget.
However, only a few fonts can be selected, none of which is monospaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible, because widgets are HTML, CSS, and JavaScript based. Here's how:

First, **go to** `/Library/Widgets` and find the Stickies one. Copy it to `~/Library/Widgets` and name it `myStickies` (or something else).

**Close** the Stickies widget in Dashboard.

Now, **go to** the `myStickies.wdgt` version you copied and **right-click** it. Choose `Show Package Contents`.

In the new window that appears, **right-click** on the `Stickies.js` file and **open** it with your favorite JavaScript editor (if you don't have one, [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) is great and free).

Now, use the editor to **find** the line `var fontArray = new Array;` (should be around line 407). You'll see below that line a bunch of lines similar to each other, saying something like 
`fontArray["font name"] = 1,`. You want to **copy** the last one of those (American Typewriter), and **paste** it back below itself. Then, **change** it so it looks like this: `fontArray["Courier New"] = 8;`

**Save** and **close** this file.

Now, **open** (from the same folder) `Stickies.html` in an HTML editor (TextWrangler works).

**Find** the line that says, 
`<select id='font-popup' class='popup' onchange='fontchanged(this);'>` (should be about line 40).

Below that, you'll **find** a bunch of lines similar to each other, each beginning with `<option value`. **Copy** the one for Gill Sans, and **paste** it below itself.
**Edit** it to say `<option value ="Courier New">Courier New</option>`.

**Save** and **close** this file.

**Open** Terminal and **type** `killall Dock`. This restarts Dashboard.

Now, **double click** the myStickies widget file you made. It will open in Dashboard. **Follow the normal procedure** of clicking the `i` and changing the font. You'll have a Courier option, and it will be that font. 
[Yay!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgDiN.png)